# excel macro insert text in every other row

Tags: excel, vba

i have an excel macro  that i recorded, but i want to do it in every row. Can someone help me out with it?

```
Sub Macro1()
'
' Macro1 Macro
'

'
    Rows("3:3").Select
    Selection.Insert Shift:=xlDown, CopyOrigin:=xlFormatFromLeftOrAbove
    Selection.Insert Shift:=xlDown, CopyOrigin:=xlFormatFromLeftOrAbove
    Range("A1:C1").Select
    Selection.Copy
    Range("A4").Select
    ActiveSheet.Paste

    Rows("6:6").Select
    Application.CutCopyMode = False
    Selection.Insert Shift:=xlDown, CopyOrigin:=xlFormatFromLeftOrAbove
    Selection.Insert Shift:=xlDown, CopyOrigin:=xlFormatFromLeftOrAbove
    Range("A1:C1").Select
    Range("C1").Activate
    Selection.Copy
    Range("A7").Select
    ActiveSheet.Paste
End Sub
```

Something like this

BEFORE:
http://i58.tinypic.com/2i9ko5s.png

AFTER
http://tinypic.com/view.php?pic=wa6a8n&s=8

SOLUTION

```
Sub test()
   Dim Last As Integer, emptyRow As Integer
   Last = Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
    For emptyRow = Last To 3 Step -1
        If Not Cells(emptyRow, 1).Value = "" Then
            Rows(emptyRow).Resize(2).Insert
            Range(Cells(emptyRow + 1, "A"), Cells(emptyRow + 1, "C")).Value = Array("School Year", "Term", "Section ID")
        End If
    Next emptyRow
End Sub
```

Comment: just like in the example

Answer (score 0):

Here is how you can do something in every other row

```
Sub EveryOtherRow()
Dim iRow As Integer
iRow = 2

Do While iRow < 1000
'check to see if it is an even row
If iRow Mod 2 = 0 Then
    'do something
End If
iRow = iRow + 1
Loop


End Sub
```